# How to add custom color to navigation bar in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, navigationbar

How do I set the navigation bar to a custom color (e.g. dark green) ?

I know how to change the navigation bar to primary colors like green and red, using code like this:

```
UINavigationBar *bar = [self.navigationController navigationBar]; 
[bar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using RGB values like this:

```
UINavigationBar *bar = [self.navigationController navigationBar];
[bar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0]];
```

Comment: Thanks this is working but can i know what will be the RGB value for dark Green color

Comment: i have got the color but i now want to make my bar little opaque .How is it possible.Thanks

Comment: Second line of code should read [bar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0]];

Comment: Onwards iOS7 `setTintColor` not works. Use `setBarTintColor ` instead.

Answer (score 14):

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:107.0/255.0 green:145.0/255.0 blue:35.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

Place this code in Appdelegate's `didfinislaunching` method.It will change the color of the navigation bar for the whole app.

Comment: Sorre should't you devide by 255 instead of 256?

Comment: @PaperThick Thanks for bringing this into notice.

Comment: It isn't working for me. Could it be that loading my view somehow overrides it?

Comment: @9000 may be in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear is overwriting this.You can cross check in your view controller.

Comment: My mistake, I thought this was about the status bar. Different from a navigation bar.

Answer (score 4):

And to change the tint of the **navigation bar background** :

```
[self.navBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.701 green:0.926 blue:0.000 alpha:1.000]];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[bar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0]]
```

There are many other ways of getting your color from different kinds of components as described in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006892-CH3-SW15).

Answer (score 3):

For swift, to change the tint of the navigation bar background :

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
```

Answer (score -1):

Use like this,

```
UINavigationBar *bar = [self.navigationController navigationBar];
bar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: Seems essentially the same as the accepted answer.